# hunspell in RStudio on Linux

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, hunspell, fedora-25

I can't make hunspell work in a script executed in RStudio.

I'm running Rstudio V1.0.136 with R V3.3.2 on a linux fedora 25. I've tried on Windows, there is no problem. And also no problem if I use the R console (on Linux and Windows).

Here's the problem:

```
library("hunspell")
words <- c("qqqqaaaa", "dddddd", "wine")
hunspell::hunspell_check(words,dict = dictionary("en_US"))
```

will return TRUE TRUE TRUE instead of FALSE FALSE TRUE

Also, running the following code makes RStudio crash

```
library("hunspell")
dictionary("en_US")
```

in rdesktop.log I have the following log, but it's not obvious that this is what makes RStudio crash but tt is to notice that the path /home/fedora/ does not exist on my machine.

> 14 Mar 2017 13:52:35 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 111 (Connection
>   refused); OCCURRED AT: void
>   rstudio::core::http::LocalStreamAsyncClient::handleConnect(const
>   boost::system::error_code&)
>   /home/fedora/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/LocalStreamAsyncClient.hpp:119;
>   LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const
>   rstudio::core::Error&)
>   /home/fedora/rstudio/src/cpp/desktop/DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:288

Also, hunspell::dicpath() return different result whether in RStudio or in R console

From RStudio:

```
> hunspell::dicpath()
 [1] "/home/myuser"                          "/usr/lib64/R/library/hunspell/dict"     
 [3] "/home/myuser/Library/Spelling"         "/usr/local/share/hunspell"              
 [5] "/usr/local/share/myspell"                "/usr/local/share/myspell/dicts"         
 [7] "/usr/share/hunspell"                     "/usr/share/myspell"                     
 [9] "/usr/share/myspell/dicts"                "/Library/Spelling"                      
[11] "/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/dictionaries"
```

From the R console:

```
hunspell::dicpath()                                                                                                                                                  
 [1] "/home/myuser"                     "/usr/lib64/R/library/hunspell/dict"                                                                                          
 [3] "/home/myuser/Library/Spelling"    "/usr/local/share/hunspell"                                                                                                   
 [5] "/usr/local/share/myspell"           "/usr/local/share/myspell/dicts"                                                                                              
 [7] "/usr/share/hunspell"                "/usr/share/myspell"                                                                                                          
 [9] "/usr/share/myspell/dicts"           "/Library/Spelling"                                                                                                           
[11] "/dictionaries"
```

Is there something to change in the RStudio configuration?